# MFC C++ Dialog based application UI

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2019, dialogbasedapp

I am developing a MFC dialog based windows application in VS2019 C++. Is there any library available for the UI design, such as adding background images, colors, font styles, buttons etc?

If anyone has any suggestions regarding the UI design of MFC C++ dialog applications, please tell me. I want to have a modern style UI and it is also not possible to change the framework.

Comment: Does it have to be in VS2019? Making UI:s in C++ programs in newer versions of Visual Studio is afaik really painful. You could look into alternatives such as C++ Builder where it's very easy to create native Windows apps in C++ with nice GUI:s.

Comment: yes, the application is already developed in VS2019. So using other alternatives is not possible.

Comment: MFC supports every single of those you named. The issue here really is, that you aren't sufficiently familiar with MFC (or the Windows API for that matter). Go get a few books (Prosise on MFC, and Petzold on the Windows API). You will not make progress if you skip reading either of those.

Comment: There has also been some community efforts trying to make it possible to use the Forms Designer with C++ projects - but the add-on I tried wasn't working too well (and it was in German if I remember correctly).

Comment: The resource editor doesn't help you in setting background images, colors, or font styles.